# Update records give error with trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, triggers

I have code like

```
UPDATE `crm_listings` SET `baths` = CASE 
WHEN `id` = '6' THEN '4'
WHEN `id` = '5' THEN '4'
ELSE `baths` END, `updated_by` = CASE 
WHEN `id` = '6' THEN '1'
WHEN `id` = '5' THEN '1'
ELSE `updated_by` END
WHERE `id` IN('6','5')
```

It give me error `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Note: There is also trigger on the same table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER crm_listings__au AFTER UPDATE ON crm_listings FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO crm_listings_versions SELECT 'update', NULL, NOW(), d.*
FROM crm_listings AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id;
```

I guess the issue is with trigger! What can be the issue?

Comment: I assume you are trying to insert some rows via trigger, and the columns and the values are not matching in it.

Comment: What is the structure of your table, `crm_lisitngs_versions`?

Comment: That is a lengthy table with more than 30 fields